# How to scale primeng components when root element font-size is set?

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm working on a project that the root font-size is set to 62.5% (10px).
`

```
html {
    font-size: 62.5%;
}
```

Now the primeng components are included in this project but they are too small. because primeng components work with `rem` units.
As said in primeng documentation:

> PrimeNG utilizes rem units to make sure the components blend in with the rest of your UI perfectly. This also enables scaling, for example changing the size of the components is easy as configuring the font size of your document. If you reqire bigger or smaller components, just change this variable and components will scale accordingly.

The problem is that if I change root font-size other elements in the project begin to get bigger because all css styles are in `rem` unit and root font-size is set to 10px.

What can I do?

Comment: you can make theme the components in the the main sass file. If you have access to prime designer you can download a whole set of sass files, then you can adjust the rem values in those throughout. or just make overrides in the components you use.